# Probleme with Spring application, maven multi module and intelliJ Comunity

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project with a parent maven module that contains no sources and 4 child modules.
It's supposed to be a Spring Application, the class having `SpringApplication.run(XXX.class, args);` is in a child module.

As I work with intelliJ community I don't have the spring plugin that could help me launch easely the application.

If I `clean install` the project everything builds correctly.

To start the application i try to right click on the class booting Spring and then click on run.
As intelliJ tries to build the app i get the following message :

> Failed to execute goal on project XXX : Could not resolve dependencies
> for project XXX:XXX:jar:0.0.28: Failed to collect dependencies at
> XXX:XXX:jar:0.0.28: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
> XXX:jar:0.0.28: Could not transfer artifact XXX:YYY:pom:${ZZZ_version_module} from/to
> releases (http://nexus...): Authorization failed for
> http://nexus.../.../.../$%257BZZZ_version_module%257D/...-$%257BZZZ_version_module%257D.pom
> 403 Forbidden

From what i understand the problem is that when building, intelliJ only build the child module, so it cannot turn the variablized version in my pom.xml `${ZZZ_version_module}` into the right version using properties from the parent pom.

Because of my work, I cannot use any plugin in intelliJ or any other dependency in my pom that could help me.

Do any one have any solution to run the SpringApplication ?

Parent pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>ABC</groupId>
    <artifactId>XYZ</artifactId>
    <version>${ZZZ_version_module}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    
    <properties>
        <ZZZ_version_module>0.0.28</ZZZ_version_module>
        ...
    </properties>
    
</project>
```

Child pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ABC</groupId>
        <artifactId>XYZ</artifactId>
        <version>${ZZZ_version_module}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    
</project>
```

(Sorry for the broken english)

Comment: Why are you using `${ZZZ_version_module}` ? Furthermore please try to build first on plain command line...

Comment: The `${ZZZ_version_module}` is the version of the parent pom wich is also given to the child module so they have the same version.
About building on plain command line, do you mean `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: Does not work using a property. Put literal values in there...

Comment: Yeah putting a literal value here works. I'm gonna do that for now as I see no other way around

Comment: See https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html